# Finding expression

Tags: probability, statistics

I don't understand this at all..

We have a Poisson distribution with parameter μ. The probability to pass the test (for the students) is p=2/3.
Let X be the amount of students to pass the test.
Find an expression for P(X=k). Which probability distribution does X have?

This is more or less my homework problem. Finding the expression for P(X=k). What does it mean? Am I wrong if I think that the X is an uniform distribution? Because for all students that pass the test, the probability is the same?

Thanks

Comment: To my knowledge, finding the expression for $P(X=k)$ means to find an expression for the probability that the number of students that pass the class is *equal* to some (arbitrary) constant value.

Comment: Let Y denote the number of students who **try** the test. Apparently Y is Poisson with parameter µ. Can you compute the distribution of X conditionally on Y? And deduce the distribution of X?

Comment: The random variable $X$ does not have uniform distribution. After some work, or perhaps intuition, you can find that it has Poisson distribution, with a parameter different from $\mu$.

Comment: But, the chance to pass the test is for all students the same?

Comment: OP How does the accepted answer answer the question *Find(ing) the expression for P(X=k)*?

Comment: It doesn't really answer the question but it was a good hint. I try to work on this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classical example for Poisson distribution is the number of spelling mistake in Pages of a book. In the same notion, here $X$ is a poisson random variable with some mean $\mu$ and the expression $P(X=k)$ is the probability of the exact $k$ student passed in the examination.

Comment: P(X=k)=μ^k/k! e^-μ..? I really must learn to write this propperly.